# Are there mockups for the desktop-oriented Unity?

Tags: unity

The [Launchpad page](https://blueprints.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-specialized-unity-form-factor) for the desktop-oriented version of Unity lists the following features separating it from the netbook version:

- A floating Unity Dash that can be moved to all edges of the screen
- Floating, overlapping windows with their title bars and controls on them, not on the top panel
- The home screen consolidated into a simple pop-down menu that extends down from the top left of the screen and allows you access to your programs and desktop search

I have some trouble picturing these, are there available mockups somewhere that could help us get an idea?

Comment: Are there actually plans to create a desktop-orientated unity?

Comment: That Launchpad page, like this question, seem to be a bit out of date. Last I've heard, Unity was intended to be the same across all machines regardless of form factor. Perhaps this question is too localized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No not yet. I'm sure we'll see some mockups, if not runnable code, in the coming month or so though.